# Beautifulsoup can't pull right info from social media sites

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, social-media

I'm trying to build a program that will scrape the top social media profiles of a certain influencer and then spit out relevant information like how many followers they have. I the gathering of the profile links seems to be working. My issue is that I can't figure out how to grab the follower count from a TikTok (or any other site at this point) web page. Does anyone have any tips on how to grab this information? I'd also appreciate any tips on how to make this code cleaner/faster as this project is the first time I've really used Python. I'm good with Java, though.

```
from googlesearch import search
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request, response, error, parse
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests


results = []
query = input("search: " )

def doSearch(tldIn, num):
    tiktok = "false"
    instagram = "false"
    facebook = "false"
    snapchat = "false"
    twitch = "false"
    youtube = "false"
    tiktok = "false"
    twitter = "false"
    bday = "false"
    for url in search(query, tld=tldIn, stop=num): 
        #This is all so I don't get multiple links to their profile. 
        #Twitter is the biggest culprit here since Google likes to embed tweets in its search results
        if "tiktok.com" in url and tiktok == "false":
           tiktok = "true"
           results.append(url)
        if "instagram.com" in url and instagram == "false":
           instagram = "true"
           results.append(url)
        if "facebook.com" in url and facebook == "false":
           facebook = "true"
           results.append(url)
        if "twitter.com" in url and twitter == "false":
           twitter = "true"
           results.append(url)
        if "snapchat.com" in url and snapchat == "false":
           snapchat = "true"
           results.append(url)
        if "twitch.com" in url and twitch == "false":
           twitch = "true"
           results.append(url)
        if "youtube.com" in url and youtube == "false":
           youtube = "true"
           results.append(url)
        if "famousbirthdays.com" in url and bday == "false":
           bday = "true"
           results.append(url)
           
def scrapeSites():
    for i in results:
        site = i
        #print('site:' + site)
        html = requests.get(site)
        print(html.status_code)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'lxml')
        #number = soup.find(class_='number').text
    
        """title = soup.title 
        titleText = title.get_text()"""
        #print(titleText)
        if "tiktok.com" in i:
            print(soup.prettify())
            foll = soup.find_all('div', class_='number')
            print(foll)
            h2 = soup.find_all('h2', class_='count-infos')
            for elem in h2:
                wrappers = elem.find_all('number')
                for x in wrappers:
                    followers = x.find('strong', title_='Followers').getText()
                    print("TikTok FOllowers: " + followers)
       
        
    
doSearch('com', 10)
if len(results) < 3:
    results.clear()
    doSearch('com', 20)
scrapeSites()
print(*results, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: _My issue is that I can't figure out how to grab the follower count from a TikTok (or any other site at this point) web page._ Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Not related but just a small thing: for your variables, you should probably just 1. Have them all in a dictionary instead and 2. replace "true" with True and "false" with False so they are just plain boolean values i.e. `social_media = {'facebook': False, 'twitter': True}` etc. Then in your if statement you could just use `if social_media['facebook']` as this would either return True or False

Comment: Well, your question popped up in the **Java** Stack Overflow tag (I'm python illiterate)... So... I just thought I'd bring up one thing.  **Java, Python** - it is not going to make too much of a difference which you use.  There are ***two points*** you need to know about **all of the social media platforms.** ① The all have programmatic API's.  They are a little complicated to read (Here, for instance, is [`Facebook's API`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/).  And ② There pages are loaded with `<SCRIPT>` such that using **Selenium** is generally the only way to scrape those pages

Comment: **Most Important** Once you get to know and use a **REST API** (which they have), it really turns out to be **a lot easier** than trying to build a complicated **Selenium** (HTML) scrape.  Generally, if you read about **REST** (**Facebook's** is called 'graph'), you can avoid learning **Selenium** because instead the whole `API` sort of just boils down to using a simple **JSON Parser.**  Learning how to use and parse **JSON** doesn't take much time at all, and it is actually the ***preferred way*** to interact with social media platforms.

Comment: Here is the [`TikTok API`](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/android-quickstart)